# INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `UserTmp` (
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`nb_invit` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`nb_share` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`nb_sent` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`total` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And i want to execute 3 queries like this (one per table in order to have nb_share, nb_invit and nb_sent) :

```
INSERT INTO UserTmp (user_id, nb_share)
  select user_id, count(share_date) as 'nb_share' 
  from Share 
  where share_date between '2012-05-21 00:00:00' and '2012-05-28 00:00:00'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nb_share=VALUES(nb_share);
```

with the nb_share field is equals to the number of share of the curent user which exists in table and require an UPDATE

The goal is to have the list of users with them numbers of actions and a total field which is the sum of actions done by an user.

VALUES(nb_share) seams to give to me the total of nb_share by all users and not by the current user.

Have you an idea to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to group the `SELECT` by `user_id`:

```
INSERT INTO UserTmp (user_id, nb_share)
  SELECT   user_id, count(share_date)
  FROM     Share
  WHERE    share_date BETWEEN '2012-05-21 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-28 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY user_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nb_share = VALUES(nb_share)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a user-defined variable:

```
INSERT INTO UserTmp (user_id, nb_share)
  SELECT   user_id, @nbshare := count(share_date)
  FROM     Share
  WHERE    share_date BETWEEN '2012-05-21 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-28 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY user_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nb_share = @nbshare
```